# has_many loop undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a has_many association in which I want to display in a table. Each Agent can make up to 3 sales, but I want to list them in the same row as the Agent.

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass on the <% sales.each do |s| %> line.
```

I'm getting the above error, event though there is defiantly data present for each column

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Agent</td>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Product</td>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Product</td>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Product</td>
        <td>Price</td>
    </tr>
    <% @agent.sales.each do |agent, sales| %>
    <tr>
        <td><% agent.name %></td>
        <% sales.each do |s| %>
        <td><%= s.date %></td>
        <td><%= s.product %></td>
        <td><%= s.price %></td>
        <% end %>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: How are you defining `@agent` and what does that `@agent.sales` give you?

Comment: Trial is just calling the params on the :id. @agent.sales gives me: #<Sale::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fdd13981000>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, since `@agent.sales` is an `ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy`, you can think of this object more like an array, rather than a hash.

How you initially wrote your loop it appears you were treating it like a hash:

`@agent.sales.each do |agent, sale|` > this syntax is saying for each key-value pair in the hash, do something with the key (`agent`) and value (`sale`).

The second time you try to run a loop, you're running it on the "value" part of the iterator, which does not exist, hence the error on the line `sales.each do |sale|`

Really, you are very close but are overthinking it. Just drop your first iterator and keep the rest:

```
<tr>
  <td><% @agent.name %></td>
  <% @agent.sales.each do |s| %>
    <td><%= s.date %></td>
    <td><%= s.product %></td>
    <td><%= s.price %></td>
  <% end %>
</tr>
```

By the way, you can apply the same principle and refactor your headers too:

```
<tr>
  <td>Name</td>
  <% 3.times do |n| %>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td>Product</td>
    <td>Price</td>
  <% end %>
</tr>
```

This assumes that your constraint is 3 max sales.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Agent</td>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Product</td>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Product</td>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Product</td>
        <td>Price</td>
    </tr>
    <% @agent.sales.each do |sale| %>
    <tr>
        <td><% @agent.name %></td>
        <td><%= sale.date %></td>
        <td><%= sale.product %></td>
        <td><%= sale.price %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```